# Get the sender of the message for an NSInvocation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime, message-passing, nsinvocation

How do I get the sender of the message wrapped in an `NSInvocation?

I'm in an object, and I've just received an invocation in my `forwardInvocation:`.
Is there any way to know who sent me the message in the first place?

Comment: You may not be able to get the 'sender' as an object, but it is theoretically possible to get the calling function, as that should be somewhere on the stack, or in the link register. Probably not useful in 95% of applications, though.

Comment: Hmm... what would that function look like, is it something general or can I extract some information about the sender from it.

Comment: You could use NSThread's `callStackSymbols` as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Information about the sender is not available (unless you explicitly add an `sender:self` argument).

See also this thread http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/194746-is-the-sender-of-an-obj-method-implied-in-the-destination-method.html:

> It isn't explicitly available, nor can you consistently unwind the
>   stack to figure it out.  Nor is there even a guarantee that the
>   "sender" is really some Objective-C object;  it could just as easily
>   be a function or FFI produced closure, in the case of the various
>   language bridges.
>
> b.bum